# How to fix Error : variable is read-only in react-native?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

### How to fix Error : variable is read-only in react-native ?

When i trying to used key of Asyncstorage in another screen.Then it give me this below error.

Please help me how i can solved it.Thank you in advanced.

[image]

This code is for store value of my API response in Asyncstorage.

```
let iGuserData = response.ResponseCode;
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('updateddata',JSON.stringify(iGuserData) )
                    console.log("async updated data",iGuserData);
```

This is my constantData.js file code.where i trying to add key of Asyncstorage.

```
export const identfyGenderData= 'updateddata'
```

This is some part of code of my welcomescreen.js file code.Where i trying to access value of Asyncstorage.

```
import {identfyGenderData} from '../Component/constantData';
const profilefirst= AsyncStorage.getItem(identfyGenderData)

componentDidMount(){this.userExist()}
  userExist=()=>{

    if (profilefirst=1) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('InterestedinScreen')
    }else{
      this.props.navigation.navigate('IdentifygenderScreen')
    } 
  }
```

Comment: share code please.

Comment: Okay wait a minuite@GauravRoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncStorage is an async function, So wait until AsyncStorage fetch `identfyGenderDatainside` using Async/await.

```
userExist = async () => {
  try {
    const profilefirst = await AsyncStorage.getItem(identfyGenderData);
    if (profilefirst == 1) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("InterestedinScreen");
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("IdentifygenderScreen");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.